# Enviar una captura de una zona de mi página web al clipboard

Tags: javascript

En [este sitio](https://www.marzenit.net) he desarrollado una web para diseñar acordes para guitarra.

Tengo un botón para capturar el DIV con la imagen del acorde.
Ya funciona teóricamente todo, no hay errores, pero una vez en el clipboard, si voy a un documento WORD por ejemplo para pegar la imagen y hago Ctrl-V para pegarla, lo que pega es un "churro" de este tipo:
`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFoAAACNCAYAAAA3k22VAAAEb0lEQVR4Xu2dMVLbQBSG1zMJzIQUlDkCLT4FfZKCisJcghm7ghvQuqHBBUnPAajhEhShcxEyA8kMYQ2yZVuW3660P5b53MGs9e9++vX26e1aajn39OT4JCfQ8qAfHv8lF3rPApsbHxygBQ4oBP3n/rdAer0lPm19nhrgQtDb29vrTSLh6IbDoQN0QsDZoQEtgOwlAN0E0K3Wc3Ly+jk+PnbdblfU7ebJRDvaQ`......

No pega la imagen real real como cuando hacemos una captura de pantalla con la tecla "Impr Pant".

Para pegar la imagen al clipboard utilizo las utilidades `dom-to-image` y básicamente este es el código Javascript:

```
function fotografiarAcorde() {
   var node = document.getElementById('nodoAcorde');
   domtoimage.toPng(node).then(function(resultado) {
      this.imagenAClipboard2(resultado);
   })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
   });
}

function imagenAClipboard2(imagen) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(imagen).then(function() {
      console.log('Imagen copiada correctamente!');
    }, function(err) {
      console.error('Error:', err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Estás haciendo `navigator.clipboard.writeText`. Deberías copiarlo con `.write` como tipo blob. Pero además, te advierto de los [problemas de compatibilidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write) de navegadores que hay...

Comment: Si, pero con clipboard.write también da errores:
Firefox: navigator.clipboard.write is not a function
Chrome: Failed to execute 'write' on 'Clipboard': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence

Comment: Pues eso es lo que digo... que copiar a Clipboard es un método que no es compatible con todos los navegadores, así que en mi opinión lo normal sería **generar un png/jpg nuevo descargable** con una librería de generación de imágenes a partir de los acordes que haya definido tu usuario, en lugar de hacer una especie de captura de pantalla